# Multiplication of two matrices in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want two find multiplication of two matrices in Simulink. Is it possible to read A and B matrices from Workspace and find multiplication of them in simulink? Which block should I use to read those data? Is From workspace block designed for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, the From Workspace block is designed for importing a **signal** from the workspace, that is a variable which is time-dependent. You don't say in your question, but it sounds like your matrices are constant **parameters**, which do not vary with time. Please make sure you understand the fundamental difference between a parameter and a signal, it's a common mistake many people new to Simulink make.

To answer your question, you should use the [Constant](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/constant.html) blocks, parameterised with the matrices' variable names. Then, simply use the [Product](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/product.html) block, making sure to set the "Multiplication" drop-down parameter to "Matrix" instead of the default "Element-wise".

Comment: The matrix I'm going to inter has a variable parameter that should be estimated.

P.S: I'm simulating an adaptive sliding mode control problem.

Comment: Your question isn't clear and/or lacks information. If your matrices are constant, then use constant blocks. If you have a timeseries, i.e. your matrices are a function of time and already define in the MATLAB workspace, use the From Workspace blocks. If you construct your matrices on the fly, then use something like [Vector Concatenate or Matrix Concatenate blocks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/vectorconcatenate.html).